# How to avoid "pointing to same object" while creating nested dictionary using zip and map?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, pointers

I would like to avoid pointing to the same object in the below code. Please look at output and desired output stated below.

Code:

```
import random
prototype = [{'uniqueDict': list()}]

def mapme(somekey):
    global aa
    aa = [random.randint(0, 5), random.randint(6, 10)]
    return dict(zip(aa, len(aa) * prototype))



forSomeKey = ['outer']
FirstSecondOnce = dict(zip(forSomeKey, list(map(mapme, forSomeKey))))

for key in aa:
    location = [['first', 'second']]
    for ixy in location:
        FirstSecondOnce[forSomeKey[0]][key]['uniqueDict'].append(ixy)

print(FirstSecondOnce)
```

Output:

```
{'outer': {0: {'uniqueDict': [['first', 'second'], ['first', 'second']]}, 7: {'uniqueDict': [['first', 'second'], ['first', 'second']]}}}
```

Desired output:

```
{'outer': {0: {'uniqueDict': [['first', 'second']]}, 7: {'uniqueDict': [['first', 'second']]}}}
```

Notice that the `['first', 'second']` is appended only once in each key loop iteration, but since they are pointing to same object. I have tried both `.copy()` and `deepcopy(prototype)` for `prototype`, but none has worked. Please suggest how to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: `len(aa) * prototype` produces a list with multiple copies of *the same* `{'uniqueDict': list()}`. The empty list here was *already created*; `list` will *not* be called again each time. `list()` means the same (unless `list` is replaced) as `[]`, but is slower. So, once the actual problem is isolated, it is the same as in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Aside from the aliasing issues, the fact that you're using a global `aa` is bizarre, especially since you then `map` the global-using function over a list. The list happens to only have one element, but if it'll always have only one element, `map` is pointless, and if it'll ever have more, previous values of `aa` will get stomped.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know what you mean but I would say not multiple copies of the same object, multiple *references* to the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do the `prototype` thing:

```
return {x: {'uniqueDict': []} for x in aa}
```

Trying to deep-copy a template object in Python will usually be slow, error-prone, and awkward, compared to creating a new object the same way you would have created the template.

Comment: If the goal is to separate out the logic, `prototype` can be implemented as a *function* instead, which `returns` a fresh version `{'uniqueDict': []}` and is *called* where needed.